# SQL statement with python and flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a SQL statement in Python; a function accepts the search word from the HTML page in flask; I want to search in the column (conceptname) has (pray, prayers, pray with, prayers day, etc..), so if the user types "pray" all this result must come, but I wrote this code and it is not working:

```
def getconceptEnglish(self, concept):
    try:
        sql = "Select Hadith from EnglishHadith where(Conceptname like '%?%')";

        values = [concept];
        self.cursor.execute(sql, values);
        result = self.cursor.fetchall();

        return result;
    except pypyodbc.Error as err:
        return err;
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? What do you mean by 'not working'? Throws an error or gives you unexpected results?

Comment: @Zondo ,I am using SQL server database,i did not get Result.this Error will show(The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.)

Comment: I think you meant that for @Dany.